# iOS KeyChain secItemAdd crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I'm trying to work with KeyChain and without a wrapper. But my code crashes when I want to read the value.

Code:

```
CFDictionaryRef attributes = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 5, NULL, NULL);

CFDataRef result;
OSStatus status = SecItemAdd(attributes, (CFTypeRef *)&result);
if (status == errSecSuccess) {
  if (result && CFGetTypeID(result) == CFDataGetTypeID()) { //crashes here
    NSLog(@"Data");

  }


  isSuccess = YES;
} else {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error while inserting into keychain osstatus:%ld\n", status);
}
```

Error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

What am I doing wrong? I thought SecItemAdd can return the newly add item

Edit:

```
const void *keys[] = {
    kSecClass
  , kSecAttrAccessible
  , kSecAttrService
  , kSecAttrAccount
  , kSecValueData
};

const void *values[] = {
    kSecClassGenericPassword
  , kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked
  , (__bridge CFStringRef)service
  , (__bridge CFStringRef)account
  , data //CFDataRef
};
```

Comment: What are "keys" and "values" declared as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation:

> To obtain the data of the added item as an object of type CFDataRef,
>   specify the return type key kSecReturnData with a value of
>   kCFBooleanTrue.

Comment: I thought this only had to be done on SecItemCopyMatching. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The answer to why you're getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS, is because the dictionary that you pass into SecItemAdd has to be mutable.

Try something like this:

> CFMutableDictionaryRef attributes = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, size,
>   &kCFCopyStringDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
>   &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
>
> CFDictionaryAddValue(attributes, keys[x], values[x]);